# Some users are missing in Mixpanel

Tags: android, mixpanel

Faced a issue when some users are si,ply missing in Mixpanel.

That occurs quite often, like 1 from 4 users is missing in Mixpanel although it is saved in DB and registered as "active user".

I'm not sure but thinking that the reason might be 6.x android. Is it able to block sending such data?

**Probably someone faced such issue. Please share your experience.**

Comment: We're seeing the same issue. Not sure what's up with that yet. (Not even sure the missing users are using android.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixpanel is blocked by certain adblockers, we have that issue and it's not really something you can fix. http://community.mixpanel.com/t/mixpanel-being-blocked-by-ad-blockers/503 suggests adding a server-side proxy between the client and mixpanel, but that introduces other problems (ip address geo lookup for example).